# ASP.NET MVC catch URL parameter in Controller

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, handler

I've defined such a controller `ViewProfile`.

I want to use it for the next syntax to access public user info in my project.

- /ViewProfile/Sammy
- /ViewProfile/Billy

etc...

But I don't know how to handle the 2-nd parameter in URL.

I've tried to use:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

But in the debugger, string query is always empty.

I have read about routines mapping, but really don't understand how would it help me with the determination of id or other parameters.

Comment: Try changing the name of the parameter to ID.

Comment: @ckv do you mean change method signature to the `public ActionResult Index(string ID)` ? I've tried right now, doesn't help :(

Comment: You are skipping the action parameter in the URL

Comment: @ckv I don't really undetstand how am I skipping it? What must I do for not skipping it? thanks

Comment: How are you navigating to the URL?

Comment: @ckv just typing the specified URL in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read in ASP.NET MVC Book that to get the parameter directly in the controller action just name it as ID.

> ASP.NET MVC lets you easily do this without having to confi gure
>   anything extra. ASP .NET MVC’s default routing convention is to treat
>   the segment of a URL after the action method name as a parameter named
>   ID. If your action method has a parameter named ID, then ASP.NET MVC
>   will automatically pass the URL segment to you as a parameter.

I just tried a sample app and it worked fine for me. The string i entered in the URL did get passed on to the ID parameter in the action. 
Also what i noticed is that you should provide your URL as viewprofile/index/1 or
viewprofile/index/somestring.

YOu seem to be skipping the action part.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, I've commented upper to you about new issue, don't understand why it doesn't handle. It does return to me a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: I just tried a sample app and it worked fine for me. The string i entered in the URL did get passed on to the ID parameter in the action.

Comment: If you mean the `Map.Route` part of code, then I didn't change anything, it's the same as it was created by default in VS http://ideone.com/Z0rXtg if you mean my controller work, so http://ideone.com/a7jRvl

Comment: I've trying to handle my application with the both:

/ViewProfile/1
/ViewProfile/someString

But debugger is firing only if it's the only `/ViewProfile` in URL, if there are some parameters after the slash, the debugger isn't event firing at the breakpoint.

Comment: You are not making use of the ID parameter in your controller action. Is that the way it is supposed to be

Comment: I'm a newbie to the webdev, just learning, could you help me to fix the incorrect way, please?

Comment: I am trying to help but I am not able to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think i understood. You have to specify your URL as viewprofile/index/1 or viewprofile/index/somestring

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33089/discussion-between-ckv-and-gelo-volro)

Comment: Sorry chat is blocked by my company firewall. So request you to add any comments here.

Comment: I see. What am I doing wrong? You said, that I'm using an ID argument as it isn't supposed to use. So what's the correct way? Can you provide me a tiny sample with your code, please?

Comment: How are the URLS formed. Are you manually navigating to them by typing in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm. I'm typing an ID in the address bar of my browser. Then I'm trying to catch.